# AWS RDS SQL Server Migration - Upload large backup file to AWS S3

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, database-migration

As part of on-premises SQL Server migration to AWS RDS, i need to upload an on-premises backup file which is around 20GB to an AWS S3 bucket to restore on an AWS RDS SQL Server instance. Using AWS CLI

`C:\Test>aws s3 cp C:\testfolder\mydb_02182021.bak s3://dbs3/OnPremisesBackups/mydb_02182021.bak`

It runs for some time, uploads around 2.5-3GB and just throws an error like this

`upload failed: ..\..\testfolder\mydb_02182021.bak to s3://dbs3/OnPremisesBackups/mydb_02182021.bak Connection was closed before we received a valid response from endpoint URL: "https://dbs3.s3.amazonaws.com/OnPremisesBackups/mydb_02182021.bak?uploadId=xxxxxxxxx-&partNumber=601".`

As per AWS docs, high level S3 commands breaks huge file and upload in parts. What are the options here? Take the backup into multiple files and upload them? There is another DB with 200GB backup size, how it can be done? I checked the multipart upload, it is more of Unix/Linux version - breaking the file into parts using unix commands and loading them. How does it works in Windows?

Comment: There are ways to resume S3 multi-part uploads, but it's pretty difficult from the command line. I would try a tool like CloudBerry Explorer to see if it works better for you. https://www.msp360.com/explorer/licensing.aspx It looks like `s3cmd` also supports resuming an upload https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a high-level (aws s3) command such as aws s3 cp, Amazon S3 automatically performs a multipart upload for large objects. In a multipart upload, a large file is split into multiple parts and uploaded separately to Amazon S3. After all the parts are uploaded, Amazon S3 combines the parts into a single file. A multipart upload can result in faster uploads and lower chances of failure with large files.

I believe the issue with your connection, maybe upload it to an ec2 server using ftp or scp and run the s3 cp command from there

Comment: yup...as i am connected to VPN..it was very slow. I did install AWS CLI on an on-premises server and copied the file...it was quick..